# Custom 404 and 500 pages in django with -> DEBUG = True

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to present the sample of my website to a client and it isn't quite finished yet but it is very important for me to hide the errors and to not show my codebase which django does if a server error occurs in development mode. Like so - [Django depicting what went wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9fDj.png)

Also I cannot turn DEBUG = False as in that case the media files aren't displayed as they are currently being served locally. Which won't be served if DEBUG = False.

**So is there a way to serve media files locally with DEBUG = False or to display custom 404 and 500 pages with DEBUG = True.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you replace the standard Django 404 page **TEMPORARILY**.

In your virtual environment, the path for the Django 404 template can be found at `(yourenvironmentname)/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/templates` with the name technical_404.html and technical_500.html.

Replace the following files with your custom 404 and 500 pages.

Comment: worked for me. but question is that will it also work for production? It worked on development mode

Comment: is it a temporary solution?

Comment: Hello, yes my answer is only a temporary solution, please refer to the link below for a more proper way of replacing error pages in production.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: thanks for your reply and yes, I resolved it in dynamic way

Answer (score 6):

Just add this to your urls:

```
import django

def custom_page_not_found(request):
    return django.views.defaults.page_not_found(request, None)

def custom_server_error(request):
    return django.views.defaults.server_error(request)

urlpatterns = [
    # .....
    path("404/", custom_page_not_found),
    path("500/", custom_server_error),
    #.....
]
```

#### Update:

I didn't mention it, but you need to have your custom `404.html` and `500.html` templates in your template directory.

Comment: this do not show pages when a 404 or 500 error raises but just show the pages in specific links