# I can't see my 404 and 500 custom pages in Django

Tags: python, django, web

I am trying to make custom 404 and 500 pages in my Django project, but when I use these codes I can't see any result!

views.py:

```
def handle404(request,exception):
    return render(request,'400.html',status=404)

def handle500(request):
    return render(request,'500.html',status=500)
```

url.py :

```
handler404 ='base.views.handle404'
handler500 = 'base.views.handle500'
```

i see only this page :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHQAr.png)

anybody have some suggestions to improve my code ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the `400.html` in your templates? By that, I mean you follow standard Django patterns: `app_name/templates/app_name/400.html`?

(By the way, I would strongly recommend, that you keep the names matching to the errors. That way you can fast navigate in your HTMLs and you don't have to remember what HTML handles which error)

**UPDATE**

You have to enter a specific path to the HTML into the render function.

Meaning: If your error HTML lives in the app `test_app` your path would be `test_app/400.html`:

```py
def handle404(request,exception):
    return render(request,'test_app/400.html',status=404)
```

Comment: yes i did but idont know why i have an error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have set `DEBUG=False` in your `settings.py` file.

But this worked for me:

Within my `app.views`:

```
# Handler error page 404
def handler404(request, exception):
     return render(request, '404.html', {})


# Handler error page 500
def handler500(request):
     return render(request, '500.html', {})
```

In the `return statement`, I have passed an empty context, `{}`.

Within my project's `urls.py` file:

```
handler404 = 'app.views.handler404'
handler500 = 'app.views.handler500'
```

`setting.py` file:

```
DEBUG=False
```

Comment: if i use debug = false iwill not see my static files so how to solve that?

Comment: actually i do that but istill have the same issue

Comment: You might want to see this answer here then... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63571380/15978450